# explanation of this one line expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python, and I saw a one-line python expression, but I don't really understand it. Can someone help explain the code to me? or expand the code in a traditional for loop? more specifically, what does     `{fruit:`  mean ?

```
return {fruit: basket.count(fruit) for fruit in set(basket)}
```

thanks!

Comment: Its a dict comprehension. `fruit:` is the part that defines the key for a particular element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression is called a dict comprehension (essentially, a single-line expression that creates a dictionary).

In Python a dict looks like this:

```
dictionary = {"key": "value", "anotherkey": ["some", "other", "value"]}
```

Where the right side of the `:` is the key (usually a string), and the left side of the `:` is the value assigned to the key.

You can use the dictionary to get a value from a key like this:

```
dictionary["key"]
>> "value"
```

So, a dict comprehension builds a dictionary using some expression like the one in your example.

If you have this `basket`:

```
basket = ["apple", "apple", "banana"]
set(basket)  # set() returns a set of unique items from basket.
>> {"apple", "banana"} 
basket.count("apple")  # list.count(x) returns the number of times x occurs in list.
>> 2
```

This:

```
dictionary = {}
for fruit in set(basket):
    dictionary[fruit] = basket.count(fruit)
return dictionary
```

is the same as this:

```
return {fruit: basket.count(fruit) for fruit in set(basket)}
#      {^key : ^value}  is added   for each item in set(basket)
```

and they both return:

```
{"apple": 2, "banana": 1}
```

Comment: Also, `set()` removes duplicates from `basket`. So you'll be sure that the final dict will have a unique keys.

Comment: @ChihebNexus 1) I wrote that `set()` returns a set of unique items, 2) it does not remove duplicates from `basket`. It returns a set of `basket`, which can't have duplicates. If it removed duplicates from `basket`, then `basket` would be modified, which is an important distinction since lists are mutable in python.

Comment: Yes! i didn't saw the comment. Shame on me :-( and what i meant from removing duplicates from basket, is having a new set of items which don't have any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

The code creates a dictionary that tells you the count of every fruit from the basket.

Maybe I can make it easier to understand by breaking it down. The code below is equivalent to your one-liner:

```
basket = ["apple", "apple", "pear", "banana"]

# a set is an unsorted list of unique items
uniqueFruits = set(basket)

# initialise empty dict
counts = {}

# loop through every unique fruit
for fruit in uniqueFruits:

    # how often does it come up in the basket?
    occurrences = basket.count(fruit)

    # put that number into the dict with the fruit name as value
    counts[fruit] = occurrences
```

Now the object `counts` contains the same dictionary as the one your statement returns. In our example:

```
{'pear': 1, 'banana': 1, 'apple': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a dict comprehension. It builds a dictionary from an `iterable` in a single statement. They were introduced in [pep-0274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

So for each element in the `iterable` we create a `dict` entry. With the fruit as the key and the number of times it occurs in the list as the value.

here is an example. I have assumed the content of your variable `basket`.

```
basket = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'cherry', 'orange', 'banana', 'orange', 'orange']

print( {fruit: basket.count(fruit) for fruit in set(basket)})

# or expanded as regular loop
d = {}
for fruit in set(basket):
    d[fruit] = basket.count(fruit)

print(d)
```

The `count` method is not very efficient, especially when coupled with another loop over the collection itself. A more efficient approach would be to use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(int)

for fruit in basket:
    dd[fruit] += 1

print(dd)
```

Now you iterate over the collection once exactly. Rather than once to create a set, once over the set itself and once over the list for each item in the set.

Answer (score 0):

It is a dict comprehension to form a dictionary from `baset` list which makes the fruit name the key and the count of that fruit the value. A for loop for that would be:

```
basket = ['banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple']
d = {}
for fruit in set(basket):
    d[fruit] = basket.count(fruit)

# d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 1}

x = {fruit: basket.count(fruit) for fruit in set(basket)}

# x = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent with:

```
temp_dict = {}
for fruit in set(basket):
    temp_dict[fruit] = basket.count(fruit)
return temp_dict
```